# Why I violate SonarQube java rule "Zero should not be a possible denominator"

Tags: java, sonarqube

for below codes

```
double total = 0.0;
//do something for total, anyway
return total < 10E-6 ? 0 : (1.0 / total);
```

Then sonar indicates me "Make sure "total" can't be zero before doing this division.". But if total is zero, it even won't reach 1.0/total. Is this a sonar bug, or my fault?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a bug but rather inherent limitation of the method SonarQube uses to check the code (static code analysis): SonarQube cannot generally evaluate the expressions (imagine if the condition depended on user input), so it cannot know whether the "else" branch will be executed or not.

All it sees is that you initialize `total` to `0.0`, and that you later *might* call code that tries to divide by `total` while it's still zero (it knows you didn't assign anything else into it, or found a branch where it remains zero).

Comment: Thanks. So actually there is no risk in my codes, right?

Comment: @wujunlong No, there is no risk, but you can get rid of the warning with `(total < 10E-6 || total == 0) ? 0 : (1.0 / total)`

Comment: How can I make this warning on sonarQube disappear if it is not a bug?

Comment: @Cecilia see Glains' comment.